# Existing C# project does not work in Visual Studio 2008 Professional edition

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008

I have installed Visual Studio 2008 Professional on a fresh Windows 8 system. After that my existing C#/WPF project is not working. It's giving so many build errors.

Actually the project was build in Visual Studio 2008 / Windows XP and it was working fine. But the same project is not now.

I just observed some differences in my project file.

Existing

```
<ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
```

Latest

```
<ProductVersion>9.0.21022</ProductVersion>
```

Showing Errors in xaml on xmlns

> Assembly 'Monitor' was not found. Verify that your are not missing an assembly reference.
>
> xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:Monitor.Controls"
>   xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Monitor.ViewModel"

This kind of build and compatibility issues are not documented anywhere.

If any have any ideas, please share them with me.

Comment: If you open the references I suspect some will show with an exclamation mark, which means that VS doesn't find those. If this is the case, add them back.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself. MSBuild directory was missing from C:\Program Files. Then i have copied from some other system.

Now its working without build issues.